# C# What happens to code in try statements that didn't throw an exception after one is thrown

Tags: c#

So, if I had something like this:

```
try
{
    variable =  Image.FromFile("Image1");
    variable2 = Image.FromFile("Image2");
    variable3 = Image.FromFile("Image3");
}
catch (Exception e) { }
```

What would happen if the second line threw an exception? Would variable 1 be assigned correctly and not 2 or 3? Or would it attempt to do 3 after handling the exception?

Comment: in which line it throws exception it does not continue on `try` anymore. but the changes that are made will remain

Comment: It is so trivial to test what actually happens here, why ask a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all variables are local (scoped) to the `try` block, it really does not matter because you can not access any of the variables outside of the block.

When an `Exception` is encountered control is transferred to the inner-most `catch`, there is no way to ignore it and continue at the next statement.

**Update**

With your changes, if the 2nd `FromFile` throws, then `variable` will have an `Image`.  variable2/3 will see no change (so most likely will null).

Comment: @Asourcious As per your edit, yes, `variable` will have the image, even if `variable2` throws an exception. This really is something you could have tested in 2 seconds, though.

Answer (score 1):

It falls out after the 2nd statement if that one throws. The first statement would succeed. The 3rd would never be evaluated.

Like the other poster said, it doesn't matter in this case since the variables are local and the ReadFromFile doesn't have side effects.

Answer (score 1):

The first variable named `variable` would successfully have a value assigned to it.

The exception is thrown on line two and anything after that is discarded but anything prior will execute. So to simplify this further:

- 1st statement executes .
- 2nd throws exception value is not stored in variable.
- 3,4,5... won't execute.

If you had a try/catch/finally then the finally will always execute.

If you want more in-depth breakdown of how exception handling works take a look at this article.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125470/Exception-Handling-for-C-Beginners